# Need working C# code to find neighbors of an element in a 2-dimentional array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

say array with 12 rows and 10 columns

```
int[,] array = new int[12,10];
```

and I select 0,0 it must return all neighbors of 0,0
which will be

```
0,1
1,1
1,0
```

say I want neighbors of 2,3 it must return an array of neighbors

```
1,2
1,3
1,4
2,2
2,4
3,1
3,2
3,3
```

Comment: that's not really how this site works.  have you actually tried something?

Comment: also, you haven't accepted any answers (clicking the checkmark) on any of your previously posted questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Braindead and non-performing but illustrative and quick:

```
        int[,] array = new int[12,10];

        int refx=0, refy=10;

        var neighbours = from x in Enumerable.Range(0,array.GetLength(0)).Where(x => Math.Abs(x - refx)<=1)
                         from y in Enumerable.Range(0,array.GetLength(1)).Where(y => Math.Abs(y - refy)<=1)
                         select new {x,y};

        neighbours.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

alternatively

```
        neighbours = from x in Enumerable.Range(refx-1, 3)
                     from y in Enumerable.Range(refy-1, 3)
                     where x>=0 && y>=0 && x<array.GetLength(0) && y<array.GetLength(1)
                     select new {x,y};

        neighbours.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: you are awesome i loved it this is so new to me though how do i learn these complex things?

Comment: @prx: Mostly, **[Prototype to learn](http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips)** and **[Sharpen The Saw](https://www.stephencovey.com/7habits/7habits-habit7.php)**

Answer (score 4):

```
element [x, y]

neighbor1 = x + 1, y;
neighbor2 = x - 1, y;
neighbor3 = x, y + 1;
neighbor4 = x, y - 1;
neighbor5 = x + 1, y + 1;
neighbor6 = x + 1, y - 1;
neighbor7 = x - 1, y + 1;
neighbor8 = x - 1, y - 1;
```

Obviously you need to check if those elements coordinates exists just in case the element is in a "border" of the matrix. Hard? I say no.