# Find nearby values in Array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

(I can use a Jagged or Multidimensional Array I'll just refer to a Jagged one for this question)

I have a Jagged Array[][] that has values about like this

```
 1 3 1 1 1
 1 3 3 3 1
 1 1 2 1 1
 1 3 1 3 1
 1 1 1 1 1
```

now I want to find the values immediately next to the 2 so 5 3's and 3 1's Where would I start with this for the life of me I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: Find `i, j` indices of the value you need. And access nearby values like this `arr[i-1][j], arr[i+1][j]` and so on. And of course you need to handle edge cases by checking if calculated indices are in array boundaries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need working C# code to find neighbors of an element in a 2-dimentional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640538/need-working-c-sharp-code-to-find-neighbors-of-an-element-in-a-2-dimentional-arr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the 2 is at ar[i][j], then you can search the neighboring positions with 2 for cycles like this:

```
for (int x = i - 1; x <= i + 1; x++) {    
    for (int y = j - 1; y <= j + 1; y++) {
        if (x == i && y == j)
           continue; // skip the position where your 2 is
        // do your logic here - count the value at ar[x][y]
    }
}
```

Also be careful to handle the borders of your array (don't try to access elements outside of the array).

I hope this will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this if using Linq:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] array2D = new int[,]{
        { 1, 3, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 3, 3, 3, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 2, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 3, 1, 3, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }};
        var resultList = GetNearbyValues(array2D, 2, 2);
    }

    private static List<int> GetNearbyValues(int[,] array2D, int i, int j)
    {
        var values = from x in Enumerable.Range(i - 1, i + 1)
                     from y in Enumerable.Range(j - 1, j + 1)
                     // make sure x and y are all positive
                     where x >= 0 && y >= 0 && (x != i | y != j)
                     select array2D[x, y];
        return values.Cast<int>().ToList();
    }
```