# How to get the neighbours of a cell in a matrix in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I tried to print the neighbours of any given cell by using its row index and column index in a 2D array using the following method:

```
public static List<int[,]> getAUVNieghborsCells(int [,] grid, int row, int col)
{

    List<int[,]> n = new List<int[,]>();

    //define boundaries
    int rowLen = Math.Min(row + 1, grid.GetLength(0) - 1),
        colLen = Math.Min(col + 1, grid.GetLength(1) - 1),
        rowIdx = Math.Max(0, row - 1),
        colIdx = Math.Max(0, col - 1);

    for (int i = rowIdx; i <= rowLen; i++)
    {
        for (int j = colIdx; j <= colLen; j++)
        {
            //if it is our given index, continue
            if (i == row && j == col)
                continue;

            int[,] temp = new int[1, 2];

            temp[0, 0] = i;
            temp[0, 1] = j;

            n.Add(temp);
        }
    }

  return n;
}
```

I send (4,0) but I got:

> |(4,0)||(4,1)||(5,1)||(6,0)||(6,1)|

which are wrong as they are the neighbors for (5,0) and (4,0). Where is the problem?

Comment: Please describe the expected behavior exactly. What do you expect to get as output?

Comment: It guess for 4,0 it should be 3,0;3,1;4,1;5,0;5,1 the neighboring cells.

Comment: But you don't use your array (grid) anywhere in code except in `GetLength` calls.

Comment: The code seems good to me. There should be another things which you didn't share with us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me your code works well it generated (3,0);(3,1);(4,1);(5,0);(5,1) for the (4,0) input. 
I wrote my own too and I get the same output.

```
private static List<int[,]> getNeigbores(int[,] matrix, int row, int column)
    {
        List<int[,]> result = new List<int[,]>();
        int rowMinimum = row - 1 < 0 ? row : row - 1;
        int rowMaximum = row + 1 > matrix.GetLength(0) ? row : row + 1;
        int columnMinimum = column - 1 < 0 ? column : column - 1;
        int columnMaximum = column + 1 > matrix.GetLength(1) ? column : column + 1;
        for (int i = rowMinimum; i <= rowMaximum; i++)
            for (int j = columnMinimum; j <= columnMaximum; j++)
                if (i != row || j != column)
                    result.Add(new int[1, 2] { { i, j } });
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the following code fits your needs?

```
Int32 targX = 4;
Int32 targY = 0;
Point targ = new Point(targX, targY);

List<Point> neighbours = (from x in Enumerable.Range(targX - 1, 3)
                          from y in Enumerable.Range(targY - 1, 3)
                          where (x >= 0) && (x < grid.GetLength(0)) && (y >= 0) && (y < grid.GetLength(1))
                          select new Point(x, y))
                         .Where(p => p != targ).ToList();
```

Demo code [here](http://rextester.com/GFA57452).

Comment: There is an answer here which is same with yours. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5640901/1370808